# Why std::vector::insert failed when insert duplicated element in VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, vector, stl

```
class RawPixElement{
public:
    CRawPixElement(int iRes) : m_iResolution(iRes) {
        m_szRawData = new unsigned char[iRes * iRes];
    };

    ~CRawPixElement() { if(m_szRawData) delete[] m_szRawData; };

    CRawPixElement(const CRawPixElement &elem) : m_iResolution(elem.m_iResolution) {
        m_szRawData = new unsigned char[m_iResolution * m_iResolution];
        memcpy(m_szRawData, elem.m_szRawData, m_iResolution * m_iResolution);
    };

    CRawPixElement & operator=(const CRawPixElement &elem) {
        m_iResolution = elem.m_iResolution;
        memcpy(m_szRawData, elem.m_szRawData, m_iResolution * m_iResolution);
        return *this;
    };
private:
    CRawPixElement();
public:
    int m_iResolution;
    unsigned char *m_szRawData;
};

typedef std::vector<RawPixElement> RawPixList;
RawPixList rpl;

void addElement(const RawPixElement& elem) {
    // find pos
    RawPixList::const_iterator iter = rpl.cbegin();
    for (; iter != rpl.cend(); iter++) {
        if (iter->getResolution() <= elem.getResolution()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // rpl.insert(rpl.end(), elem) is OK. but not with rpl.begin()
    rpl.insert(iter, elem);
}

int main(){
    RawPixElement e1(128);
    RawPixElement e2(32);
    RawPixElement e3(256);
    RawPixElement e4(8);
    RawPixElement e5(64);
    RawPixElement e6(32);
    addElement(e1);
    addElement(e2);
    addElement(e3);
    addElement(e4);
    addElement(e5);
    addElement(e6);  // Exception here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    return 0;
}
```

I used std::vector and wanted to sort the elements in it.
So that when adding element to vector it will insert into the indicated location by calling function 'addElement()', but not push the element to the tail of the vector by using 'push_back()'.
By this way, the vector keeps ordered when it be used.
But on VS2010, it occured an runtime error seems like stl exception when the last 'addElement()' been called in the code. And I tested the code on gcc and clang under C++11 and C++14 standard, there were also errors with both of them.
Was the way I used std::vector wrong , or IS THERE something I do not know about vector? For the record: same error would be occured when insert same sequence at 'begin iterator', but ok at 'end iterator'. I think it's unbelievable!

Comment: The class name is CRawPixElement, not RawPixElement. Sorry about the typo.

Comment: There is an edit button at the bottom of your question you can use to fix that.  Or you can use this one [edit]

Comment: Why all the manual memory management here?

Comment: why are you doing manual sorting upon insert? Best way to achieve what you are trying to do is using std::multimap<int, data>. Where data in you case can be simply defined as std::vector<byte>. Multimap will keep your inserted elements sorted automatically AND will do insertions faster.

Comment: The code is a demo to describe the issue I met, and the reason I didnt use multi-map is that the data type was defined in other modules, and I only use it just like in 'main'. Yes, I know that the multi-map can meet my requirement, AND I also want to know what the problem with vector::insert is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Need to realloc in "operator=" when the m_res bigger than the value of the old element.